# How do I resolve a build error when installing the atlas-lapack package?

Tags: makefile, lapack, atlas

I'm installing the atlas-lapack package on ArchLinux

https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/atlas-lapack

Installation is as follows:

```
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/atlas-lapack.git
cd atlas-lapack
makepkg -si
```

After quite a long installation, I received the following message

```
ATLAS install complete.  Examine 
ATLAS/bin/<arch>/INSTALL_LOG/SUMMARY.LOG for details.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/Downloads/atlas/atlas-lapack/src/ATLAS/build'
make clean
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/user/Downloads/atlas/atlas-lapack/src/ATLAS/build'
rm -f *.o x* config?.out *core*
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/Downloads/atlas/atlas-lapack/src/ATLAS/build'
make: *** No rule to make target 'libptf77blas.a', needed by 'libptf77blas.so'.  Stop.
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
    Aborting...
```

Please tell me how to solve this problem?

Blas package (https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/blas/) is already installed on the system.

upd.

Here is the contents of the makefile

```
include Make.inc

all: libatlas.so libf77blas.so libptf77blas.so libstcblas.so libptcblas.so \
   libblas.so libcblas.so liblapack.so.3.6.1 libptlapack.so.3.6.1 liblapack.so.3

libatlas.so: libatlas.a
    ld $(LDFLAGS) -shared -soname $@ -o $@ --whole-archive libatlas.a \
       --no-whole-archive -lc $(LIBS)

libf77blas.so : libf77blas.a libatlas.so
    ld $(LDFLAGS) -shared -soname libf77blas.so.3 -o $@ --whole-archive \
       libf77blas.a --no-whole-archive $(F77SYSLIB) -L. -latlas

libptf77blas.so : libptf77blas.a libatlas.so
    ld $(LDFLAGS) -shared -soname libblas.so.3 -o $@ --whole-archive \
       libptf77blas.a --no-whole-archive $(F77SYSLIB) -L. -latlas

libstcblas.so : libcblas.a libatlas.so libblas.so
    ld $(LDFLAGS) -shared -soname libstcblas.so -o $@ --whole-archive \
       libcblas.a -L. -latlas -lblas

libptcblas.so : libptcblas.a libatlas.so libblas.so
    ld $(LDFLAGS) -shared -soname libcblas.so -o $@ --whole-archive \
       libptcblas.a -L. -latlas -lblas

libblas.so: libptf77blas.so
    ln -s $< $@

libcblas.so: libptcblas.so
    ln -s $< $@

liblapack.so.3.6.1 : liblapack.a libstcblas.so libf77blas.so
    ld $(LDFLAGS) -shared -soname libstlapack.so.3 -o $@ --whole-archive \
       liblapack.a --no-whole-archive $(F77SYSLIB) -L. -lstcblas -lf77blas

libptlapack.so.3.6.1 : libptlapack.a libcblas.so libblas.so
    ld $(LDFLAGS) -shared -soname liblapack.so.3 -o $@ --whole-archive \
       libptlapack.a --no-whole-archive $(F77SYSLIB) -L. -lcblas -lblas

liblapack.so.3: libptlapack.so.3.6.1
    ln -s $< $@
```

As I understand it, I am missing the libptf77blas.a library?